# Custom protocol in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, protocols

How to make custom **protocols** work in windows phone 7? I know its achievable in windows store app using protocol declaration. Is it possible in Windows Phone 7 as well?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible on Windows Phone 7. Registering a custom URI scheme is a feature added in the WP8 SDK.

Comment: Is there any workarounds to make this work in WP7, basically I need to get this work for the links in the html files?

Comment: @user2376776 There is no known workaround for WP7. If the HTML page is loaded from your application, you can detect that the user has clicked on a link, and act accordingly. If the HTML page is loaded outside of your application (for instance, in Internet Explorer or in the mail application), there's nothing you can do.

Comment: The html is loaded in my web browser control and an anchor tag in it has a link with a custom uri schema. Is there a way to catch this click in the client code without using window.external.Notify()?

Comment: @user2376776 Have you tried subscribing to the `Navigating` event? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigating(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Navigating event does not get fired on the click , if its a custom schema uri.

Comment: @user2376776 I didn't know that. You can maybe try with `NavigationFailed`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigationfailed(v=vs.105).aspx  If it doesn't work either, I'm out of ideas